# Client from smart phone sends his/her username and password to a server via HTTP Post without any encryption, is it ok?

Tags: android, encryption, http-post

In an Android application in a smart phone,
Client sends his/her username and password to a server via HTTP Post

I wonder if it is a good procedure or not to send the username and password via HTTP Post without any encryption? 
Is this procedure prone to any kind of attacks or not?

Isn't there any automatic encryption and decryption through HTTP Post from the smart phone to the server that makes sure nobody can see the username and password or not?

> I've read some posts on this subject but non of them were about HTTP
>   Post through Android smart phone and server and all focused on HTTP through browsers and servers

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I utilize http**s** instead of http, everything is fine and there is no need for encryption and nobody can sniff the usernames and passwords sent through Https Post